# What is the correct way to configure file association in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, language-agnostic

Windows 10 has made changes to how file associations work and I'm looking for any official recommendation on how to have your application associate files automatically for the end user. I'm working in C++, but this is language agnostic as it pertains more to how Windows 10 works than what language is being used.

**What is the correct way to programmatically configure file association in Windows 10?**